# Table design with one row is correct

Tags: sql, database, settings

I have a table in the database called the print table, where print settings such as PrintWidth, PrintHeight, and PrintTtitle are stored. This table has only one row. Now my question is, Is the database an appropriate location for these settings, if answer is yes, how should the table design be?

Comment: It depends on whether the configuration option will be shared among all users or not. Assuming everything OK, it remains to ensure that the table can only have one row.

Comment: Yes, all users should have access to the print settings

Comment: I understand that the print with and height are global and apply to all users. But what about the print title? Do all users really print their data with the same print title?

Comment: This is how the software is installed in one place, for example, an organization, and this software belongs to that organization, and the title must be the same for an organization. Of course, this question did not occur to me only in this one table and it can be generalized to other situations.

Comment: Most of the time *configuration tables* have a vertical design instead of a horizontal design. That is, they typically have two columns (property_name, property_value) so they can easily be extended with more properties in the future without altering the table structure. Nevertheless, using a horizontal design is OK, if you don't foresee too many changes in the near future.

Comment: Technically, the solution is OK. Limiting to only one row is specific to the particular database, general guidance is already given in the answers. However, it is worth considering a key - value table variant (the key is unique and can be defined as the primary key for the table). That being said, you can add configuration values without having to touch the DDL

Answer (score 1):

Such tables are sometimes called singleton tables and you can implement such a table in SQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE settings
    (x CHAR(1) NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT ('X') CHECK (x = 'X')
    , PrintWidth FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
    , PrintHeight FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
    , PrintTitle VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''));

INSERT INTO settings DEFAULT VALUES;

UPDATE settings SET PrintWidth = 8.5, PrintHeight = 11, PrintTitle = 'some title';
```

The x column with uniqueness and check constraints guarantees that this table must contain, at most, one row.

It makes sense to do this if the database is the place you want to store settings. If there is intended to be only one valid value for, say, PrintTitle then that implies a functional dependency ∅→PrintTitle (∅ is the empty set of attributes). To satisfy Boyce Codd Normal Form therefore ∅ should be the key of a table containing PrintTable.

SQL's support for this situation is not ideal because uniqueness constraints do not allow empty sets of attributes. I used UNIQUE rather than PRIMARY KEY in my example settings table because x is *not* the primary key of this table; ∅ is the primary key.

Comment: And we can add a delete trigger preventing the row from ever getting deleted. And revoke the TRUNCATE right from every user.